# How to get proxy data from server in extjs store without using store.load method

Tags: extjs4

I am using extjs grid with Ajax proxy(XML reader) to load the data. The application requirement is ,Proxy will get all data from the server but than the grid should be reloaded or refresh only if it has something to add/delete.

I have searched but may be I am missing something or not searching right way.

Here is what I want to do.
1) Get initial grid data from server and rander.
2) Store the data locally.
2) After 5 seconds get server response again but compare the local data and call grid refresh only if something has changed. Do this infinitely until user goes away from this page.

My problem is how can I get Proxy.Read() or something like that to capture the XML response first time as well as any subsequent request. Once I can get the response I know how to proceed further.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Jignesh

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code as in the [AbstractStore.load](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/AbstractStore.html#Ext-data-AbstractStore-method-load) method and specify your own callback.

Comment: You mean to say replace onProxyLoad method ? Is there any way I can override the onProxyLoad method instead of modifying the store source. The problem in using the Store's load method is it will still refresh the entire grid once the load is handled by the callback. I want the grid to be refreshed only if the callback wants it.The store's load method always does refresh doesn't matter you had callback function or not.

Comment: I want something like example of using processResponse of Proxy without using store load. I don't know exact syntax but it should be like proxy.read(callback: processResponse).

Answer (score 0):

Try using
var operation = new Ext.data.Operation({
                            action: 'read'
                        });
                    store.proxy.read(operation, callbackmethod, store);

and inside callbackmethod put your logic while using operation.response.responseText to get the new data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Load the store normally. Then run Ajax.request to the server method that will calculate weather or not there was a change. If the server method says there was a change then call store load again.

In theory Websockets is the right way to have the server update the client.